# Sharing an Eclipse Java Project with referenced libraries using Saros

Tags: java, eclipse

I've build a small Java Project using a few referenced libraries (Lucene jar files that are located somewhere on my PC).

I'm trying to share the projects with a friend using Saros so we could work on it simultaneously.

everything works great aside from the fact that he can't see the referenced libraries and the app won't run on his computer.

any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

the problem was that the referenced jar files were located somewhere on my personal computer. but in my partner computer, the jar files were located elsewhere.

my suggested solution is to create a directory within the Java Project and locate all the referenced jar files there (physically).

by doing that, when the project is shared, your partner will get all the project relevant files including the directory you've created.